# Ninject Method Injection Redis

Tags: asp.net-web-api, redis, servicestack, ninject

I am trying to use Ninject to manage my Redis dependencies on a ASP.NET Web Api project. 
I do my binding like this:

```
 var clientManager = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost");
 kernel.Bind<IRedisClientsManager>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => clientManager)
    .InSingletonScope();
 kernel.Bind<IRedisClient>()
    .ToMethod(k => k.Kernel.Get<IRedisClientsManager>()
    .GetClient());
```

How can I subsequently get access to my redis client in other classes in the project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Redis, so beware...

Now that you've got a binding, you can inject it into a constructor

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(IRedisClient redisClient) {...}
}
```

Or you can use a func to access/create it at a specific time:

```
public class Foo {
    private readonly Func<IRedisClient> redisClientFunc;

    public Foo(Func<IRedisClient> redisClientFunc) 
    {
        this.redisClientFunc = redisClientFunc;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        IRedisClient client = this.redisClientFunc();
        client.SayHello();
    }
}
```

or, equivalently, you can use the ninject factory extension to achieve the same as the func, but with an interface, see https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki. Both `Func<>` and interface factory need the factory extension.

Comment: I should mention that my project is multi-tier so I have an API, Business and Repository projects in my solution with Ninject referenced in the API layer. With that being said, I already tried the constructor injection in my Repo layer but then the other places where I instantiated Foo I get the following error **"Foo does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"**. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please be *way* more specific about the exception you receive: What's the calling code, what is the exception type, what is the exception stack trace...